# How do I solve an Archiving app error - missing xmlreader.h

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, archiving

I'm archiving an app and get an error message saying that I'm missing the following:

```
#include <libxml/xmlreader.h>
```

the app builds fine on a device and simulator. I'm only getting this error when archiving.

any idea what I need to do to fix this?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the library search path and added "/usr/include/libxml2" to it. It worked and archived after that.